Need to resample or resize images in python
I have two images, want to resize these images as should be same imagedata(circles/text) with exact same pixel location of both images. The distance between objects should also be same of both images.This should be in python only. As shown in image the distance (no. of pixels) from J to 27 in both images should be same 
Thanks
I tried to resize these with same sizes( width * height) and set DPI as well but in vain.

You want to resize images but keep everything the same distance apart and at the same positions? Sounds impossible to me.

I don't want to resize at all but to adjust objects at the same positions in pixels of both images

the task is called "registration" or "alignment". it will involve resampling of one of those images. the result would match fairly well. since those are two different pictures, the result cannot be "perfect".

@ChristophRackwitz Thanks, can you share some links for this kind of implementation?

Please share your two images as two images rather than one combined image... then folks can work with two images.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the help center (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example - And Show Code As Text, Not An Image" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

if you want automatic alignment, you can have that. it will involve OpenCV, not imagemagick. please provide the two pictures.

What is your actual goal? Do you simply want to recognize the marked boxes on the sheets? Can you give examples of complete sheets, not just fragments? What have you tried so far? Can you share some code?

You seem to be wanting to do "image registration" or "image alignment" - thanks Christoph!
I split your image into two, because they were unhelpfully joined, and got these two:


I then located 3 points, as marked in red in both images:




Point
left
right




J27
262,51
118,138


A27
499,48
353,134


J29
264,140
118,224



I can then perform an "affine distortion" by specifying for each of the three points, their position in the first and in the second image with ImageMagick as follows:
magick left.png -virtual-pixel black \
   -distort affine '262,51 118,138 499,48 353,134 264,140 118,224' result.png

If I flicker between right.png and result.png, I get this:

Ideally, you would choose very well defined points near the corners of the image so that the errors are minimised - imagine balancing a plate on three fingertips and then imagine your fingertips are all very close to each other in the middle of the plate versus if they were near the edges of the plate.

This is done with ImageMagick at the command line, but you can use wand to do exactly the same thing in Python, because wand is a C-types binding to ImageMagick.
Here is a link to another distortion answer I did with wand so you can see how to port it over to Python.
